# OpenVPN - Properly sharing keys/certificates

Tags: security, vpn, openvpn, certificate, keys

I enabled OpenVPN on the router at work so that we can connect to different devices like our NAS and RDP into the computers there without opening those ports to the internet.

One cause of concern that I just noticed was the fact that the client key files have to be shared with each of the clients. If one person gets a virus and the attacker then downloads those files, they could easily connect through the VPN and have access to our entire network. (correct?) How can I prevent that from happening?

The VPN Server is on the router, so I don't have a lot of control over the whole process. I just enabled the VPN and then clicked "Download" which downloaded all of the necessary keys and certificates.

The whole purpose of using the VPN was a more secure method of using RDP but it seems it may create more potential attack methods.

Comment: Use **M**ultiple **F**actors of **A**uthentication

Answer (score 0):

You could have some other form of authentication before allowing a client to establish a VPN connection, that along with something like fail2ban and ban alerts should block any unauthorized connection, block repeating attempts and warn you so you can take action.

More info: https://openvpn.net/community-resources/using-alternative-authentication-methods/

Answer (score 0):

> One cause of concern that I just noticed was the fact that the client key files have to be shared with each of the clients. If one person gets a virus and the attacker then downloads those files, they could easily connect through the VPN and have access to our entire network. (correct?) How can I prevent that from happening?

Essentially correct. The way to reduce this is to use a username and password in addition to a key. OpenVPN supports both - [and they can be combined](https://serverfault.com/questions/420274/possible-openvpn-server-requiring-both-certificate-and-password-based-login-v).

If you need even stronger security, you can store the certificates in a smart card. The smart card can do operations using the keys, but will not give out a copy of the keys, so they are practically an uncopyable key storage; if you have the card you know only you have the key.

> The whole purpose of using the VPN was a more secure method of using RDP but it seems it may create more potential attack methods.

Any malware that can read OpenVPN secrets can probably keylog a RDP password. The point of a VPN is to reduce the attack surface on the public internet; you don't have to worry if RDP and SMB and ... is secure - you just have to worry that a single piece of software is secure. It's easier to maintain and secure that one interface.